# Ordering links in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to make a navigation bar that is order by an order tag in the yaml frontmatter of the site (the site is made with jekyll). What i want to achieve is something like this (with the order value of the page next to it)

[home1] [solutions2] [talent3] [contact4]

This is the solution i am playing with. Solutions has a dropdown box when hovered over, hence the weird if divide.

```
{% assign pages = site.pages | sort:"order" %}
{% for page in pages %}
  {% if page.categories contains "index" and page.categories <> "solutions" %}
    <li><a href="{{page.url}}">{{page.title}}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% if page.categories contains "index" and page.categories contains "solutions" %}
    <li><div class= "dropdown">
      <a href="{{page.url}}">{{page.title}}</a>
      <div class= "dropdown-content">
        <p> Our Service Solutions are:</p>
        <ul>
          {% for subpage in site.pages %} 
          ... truncated ...
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div></li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

with the frontmatter

```
---
order: 1
categories: [ 'index', 'home' ]
---
```

or in the case of solutions,

```
---
order: 2
categories: [ 'index', 'solutions' ]
---
```

(both truncated for clarity)

This, however, does not work. What happens is this:

[home1][talent3][contacts4][solutions2]

does anyone know what is happening? Thank you.

Comment: And front matters are ?

Comment: i have edited the question, let me know if I make sense.

Comment: Is the space before the colon in the frontmatter correct?

Comment: it is not. Sorry for the flaky edit, end of a long work day. Will fix.

Comment: Can you put this on a repository ?

Comment: Problem solved. Or rather, it isnt, but it turns out that the liquid is doing its job and putting them in the correct order in the _site folder, and some other thing is spitting it out in the wrong order.